# JS Numeric value UP or Down

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, quartz-composer

I have a slider which is controlling a player. The value of the slider goes between -1 and 1.

I am trying to get the code to recognise when the slider is moved up or down. I am trying using this but nothing works .

```
var slider = "input slider";


var sliderMov = 0;


if (slider == slider++){
    sliderMov = 1;
}
if (slider == slider--){
    sliderMov = 0;
}
```

Any Solution?

In Quartz Composer JavaScript Object I have so far:

```
var Numb1 = inputs[0];


Object.Numb1Fin = 0;


if (Numb1 == Numb1++){
    Object.Numb1Fin = 180;
}
if (Numb1 == Numb1--){
    Object.Numb1Fin = 0;
}

outputs[0] = Object.Numb1Fin;
```

Comment: `slider` is a string and then you increment or decrement that string?  I think you need to add more context to this code.  When is it called, etc.

Comment: yep .. is a value number between -1 and 1. This value is coming from an object in Quartz Composer

Comment: You have `var slider = "input slider";`.  It is a string.

Comment: The slider itself may have a `change` event. Which slider are you using? Need more information.

Comment: Slider from quartz composer.

Comment: What IS quartz composer? Still too vague to help you at all. A code clip would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

slider++, slider--, Numb1++, and Numb1-- will change the value of the number you are comparing after the comparison. Meaning the comparison will always be true and then the value will change or a change will be attempted. Aside from not being logical you should avoid trying to change the inputs as they should be read only. Here is some JavaScript code which should work for you:

```
var _oldNumber = null
function (__number outputNumber) main (__number inputNumber, __number patchTime)
{
    var result = new Object();
    if (!_oldNumber) _oldNumber = inputNumber;
    result.outputNumber = inputNumber == _oldNumber ? 0 : inputNumber > _oldNumber ? 1 : -1;
    _oldNumber = inputNumber;
    return result;
}
```

You'll need to connect a Patch Time patch to the Patch Time input of the JavaScript patch to force execution every frame.